# AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "logservice"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, djangoappengine

I am trying to run django in appengine locally, and I get this erro - `AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "logservice"`

What does this mean? Am I missing something in the setup?

I run it by the following command:

```
PYTHONPATH=/lib/python2.7/site-packages/  dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Full stacktrace -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 287, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 314, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/request_handler.py", line 165, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/request_handler.py", line 303, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 95, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/Users/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 322, in MakeSyncCall
    assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "logservice"
```

Comment: What's the content of your `app.yaml` file? Which version of the SDK? Side note: you may want to also tag your GAE-related questions with the more generic `google-app-engine` tag, it's much more actively monitored/visited, you'd probably get an answer faster. I added it for this post.